# Add watermark to PDF using PDFium

Tags: pdf, uwp, watermark, pdfium, pdf-annotations

I'm implementing a PDF editor on UWP using PDFium as the base library. I cannot seem to find any proper way of adding/creating watermarks on a document.

I went through the PDFium source and spec documents but didn't find anything useful.

I tried to analyze some PDF documents with watermarks but it is unclear how they are created and couldn't find a common mapping too.

Could someone please help me understand how watermarks are added to PDF documents?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm trying to add watermarks using the PDFium library.

Answer (score 0):

pdfium don't support add watermark directly. You can add page object to implement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).